# Mostrar texto contido em javascript

Tags: javascript, xamarin

Estou fazendo um jogo de perguntas e respostas, porém estou com problema no código.

O valor existe, tenho outro código com a verificação e consigo verificar os valores do checkbox.

```
var perguntas = [

  ["Qual a Capital do Brasil?", "Rio de Janeiro", "Brasilia", "São Paulo", "Minas Gerais"],

  ["Qual a Capital dos Estados Unidos?", "Nova York", "Los Angeles", "Paris", "Washington"]

];

function geraValorPergunta() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * perguntas.length);
}

function newQuestion(perguntas) {

  var numeroPergunta = geraValorPergunta();
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("perguntas");

  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.method = "post";

  var pa = document.createElement("p");
  pa.textContent = perguntas[numeroPergunta][0];

  // cria filhos
  div.appendChild(pa);
  div.appendChild(form);

  // cria input
  var criaInputs = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < perguntas[0].length; i++) {
    criaInputs[i] = document.createElement("input");
    criaInputs[i].classList.add("classeInput");
    criaInputs[i].type = "radio";
    criaInputs[i].name = "opcao";
    criaInputs[i].value = perguntas[numeroPergunta][i];
    criaInputs[i].textContent = perguntas[numeroPergunta][i];
    form.appendChild(criaInputs[i]);
  };

  var botao = document.createElement("button");
  botao.classList.add("resposta");
  botao.textContent = "Enviar";
  botao.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    verificaResposta(numeroPergunta);
  });
  form.appendChild(botao);
  return div;
}
```

O problema é o seguinte, o textcontent não aparece
no console.log, ele aparece de forma normal, porém não na página.
já tentei innerhtml, textcontent etc etc, mas não funciona, apesar de verificação da resposta funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Elementos `<input type="radio"` não podem ter texto dentro. Daí que o `textContent` ou `innerHTML` não funcionaram. Usa `<label>` assim:

```
// cria input
for (var i = 1; i < perguntas[0].length; i++) {
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.classList.add("classeInput");
    input.type = "radio";
    input.name = "opcao";
    input.value = perguntas[numeroPergunta][i];
    label.textContent = perguntas[numeroPergunta][i];
    label.insertBefore(input, label.firstChild);
    form.appendChild(label);
};
```

#### Exemplo:

```js
var perguntas = [

  ["Qual a Capital do Brasil?", "Rio de Janeiro", "Brasilia", "São Paulo", "Minas Gerais"],

  ["Qual a Capital dos Estados Unidos?", "Nova York", "Los Angeles", "Paris", "Washington"]

];

function geraValorPergunta() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * perguntas.length);
}

function newQuestion(perguntas) {

  var numeroPergunta = geraValorPergunta();
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("perguntas");

  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.method = "post";

  var pa = document.createElement("p");
  pa.textContent = perguntas[numeroPergunta][0];

  // cria filhos
  div.appendChild(pa);
  div.appendChild(form);

  // cria input
  for (var i = 1; i < perguntas[0].length; i++) {
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.classList.add("classeInput");
    input.type = "radio";
    input.name = "opcao";
    input.value = perguntas[numeroPergunta][i];
    label.textContent = perguntas[numeroPergunta][i];
    label.insertBefore(input, label.firstChild);
    form.appendChild(label);
  };

  var botao = document.createElement("button");
  botao.classList.add("resposta");
  botao.textContent = "Enviar";
  botao.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    verificaResposta(numeroPergunta);
  });
  form.appendChild(botao);
  return div;
}

var question = newQuestion(perguntas);
document.body.appendChild(question);
```

```css
form > label {
    display: block;
}
```